# How many times a day do the digits on a 6-digit clock form an increasing arithmetic sequence?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

We're talking digital clock so think of 24-Hour format HH:MM:SS where H are hours, M are minutes, and S are second.

I've thought of

$01:23:45$

and

$12:34:56$

It seems a bit tricky and I feel like I'm missing something.

Edit:
If we don't focus on the artithmetic sequence being strictly increasing the answer expands to:
$01:23:45$

$12:34:56$

$00:11:22$

$00:22:44$

$11:22:33$

$11:33:55$

$22:33:44$

Any ideas? Arguments? Anything?

Comment: Are repeated digits allowed (e.g., 11:22:33), or do you mean *strictly* increasing?

Comment: It doesn't specify that in the problem. I suppose we might consider both cases.

Comment: Yea arithmetic sequences with $d=0$

Comment: I wonder if $00:11:22$ should really be an example, because the differences between digits are sometimes $0$ and sometimes $1$.

Comment: On re-reading the question, it specifies an **increasing** arithmetic sequence, so my suggestion of including $d=0$ was, incorrect !

Comment: $13:26:39$ is an increasing arithmetic sequence.

Comment: @DanielMathias It's unclear if we should treat this as "3 numbers in an AP" or "6 digits all of which are in an AP".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the version where we interpret the question to be "The 3 numbers are in an AP",

**Hint:** Show that a necessary and sufficient set of conditions for there to be an increasing AP is

- HH goes from 00 to 24
- SS goes from 00 to 60
- HH and SS have the same parity
- HH and SS are distinct
- HH < SS
- MM = (HH + SS) / 2

Hence, conclude that the number of possibilities are ...

---

Note: Technically OP listed out 00:11:22, which isn't "6 digits which form an increasing AP", which is why I'm taking the interpretation of "HH, MM, SS form an increasing AP"